# Get List of Animators in Script

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I've got a UI menu in world space with camera flying around the canvases (representing the menu sections).

As for buttons I made some animations with separate animator for each button, so that I click "Single Player", for example, and the buttons in this canvas should be replaced (using animations) with other buttons that're outside the canvas and vice versa (when I hit "Back").

The thing is that I wanted to use List UIAnimators in the UIGameObject that holds all scripts to the scene. The problem is that Unity seems unable to receive Lists when I set the script to the button onClick thing. It doesn't show the methods with Lists at all. Is there a way to walk around it. So I can trigger several controllers in the same script, since I need to replace several buttons in the canvas using controllers of each one. Just looking for some tips, no coding needed, or maybe there are some references or tutorials. I'd really appreciate some help.

[Menu layout, just to get a picture of the idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRlzh.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure that I am following but if I understand correctly then you want to have a collection of different UI Elements and use the OnClick events from the Buttons to activate the corresponding animations for multiple elements at once.

Not sure if it is the best solution but you can make an array on the parent game object with all of your buttons with their animators and then with the OnClick event call a public function that plays the animation for the corresponding index

```
public void MyFunction(int index)
{
  myUIElements[index].GetComponent<Animator>().Play();
}
```

Then just add multiple calls to that function with indices for all of the elements that you want to animate when that button is clicked as below:

[image]